# MVC Html.BeginForm not submit by JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, model-view-controller

I have very simple form:

```
<div id="FormDiv">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyA, Model.A_Items, "--- Select A ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyB, Model.B_Items, "--- Select B ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

    }

</div>
```

and JQuery javascript for submitting form on dropdown slection change:

```
$("#PropertyA").change(function () {
    $(this).parents("form").submit();
});

$("#PropertyB").change(function () {
    $(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

but form is not submitting!!!

Although, when i remove one of dropdowns from view OR change value of any dropdown then change value of another, form is submitting as suspected!
Is this some kind of bug or how else can submit that form?

Comment: validation may be firing, both dropdown have valid value?

Comment: oh, simple as it, totally forgot about unobtrusive validation. @EhsanSajjad make it as answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chance is as your view is strongly typed, it is firing model Validation, make sure all the fields are fill and use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Property)` so that you can see on screen that which element is firing validation.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyA, Model.A_Items, "--- Select A ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => x.PropertyA)
</div>
```